# Cabal rebuild on embedded file change

Tags: haskell, cabal, rebuild

I'm using the [file-embed](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/file-embed) package thusly:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import qualified Data.ByteString.Internal as B (w2c)
import qualified Data.FileEmbed as E

initWindow = do
    b <- Gtk.builderNew
    let glade = map B.w2c $ B.unpack $ $(E.embedFile "window.glade") in
        Gtk.builderAddFromString b glade
    ...
```

Is it possible to make cabal rebuild this file even when only the glade file changes?

Comment: Have you tried using the `other-filrs` category?

Comment: Well, there's `data-files`, but I like the idea of having exactly one file to distribute. What I need is a way to make the .hs file explicitly depend on the glade file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Support for this will be/has been added in GHC 7.4/7.6. The problem is that the compiler doesn't allow TemplateHaskell splices to add file dependencies yet. See [this ticket](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/4900) for more information.

When this change lands, you can use the following code to create a new `embedFile'` function:

```
import Data.FileEmbed

import Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax
import Language.Haskell.TH.Lib

embedFile' :: FilePath -> Q Exp
embedFile' path = do
  qAddDependentFile path
  embedFile path
```

This has to be in a separate module from where you use the TH function.

Comment: This change never actually landed, so we still (eight years after this question and answer) have no way to do this.